# Conditional Select on a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am wondering how conditional select on a pandas column works. In the Below code

```
In [162]: euro16
Out[162]: {'Goals': [16, 8], 'Team': ['Germany', 'England']}

In [163]: euro16_df = pd.DataFrame(euro16)

In [164]: euro16_df[euro16_df.Team == 'Germany']
Out[164]:
   Goals     Team
0     16  Germany
```

However when you try a conditional on the team that involved string access ie: Say all teams starting with 'G'. I get a KeyError.I would greatly appreciate any information on what might be happening here.

```
euro16_df[euro16_df.Team[0] == 'G']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `str` string accessor

```
euro16_df[euro16_df.Team.str[0] == 'G']
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.  How is it that it can compare with the original string "Germany" without needing an accessor. I totally missed this while and would love to read more about this.

Comment: @Pradyot there are a bunch of methods that can be done pandas does a good job of making the most important ones available without an accessor. Otherwise pandas groups like methods together. There is also a date time/time delta accessor 'dt'. Category accessor 'cat'.

Comment: Again. Really appreciate the direction.

Answer (score 1):

Also str startswith.

```
euro16_df[euro16_df.Team.str.startswith('G')]
```